# not understanding the lyrics of a song

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I was listening to this [beautiful rework of "Make it to Heaven"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2GT411CdME) and have had some trouble understanding the lyrics from 0:50 to 1:19.

Here is what I'm hearing from the song:

> In the dark, in the dead of the night
> I will cry,
> I will cry,
> I will cry like the tough cry
>
> 'Till you gave me your drug
> Somehow sobers me up
> Hold me up,
> hold me up,
> Now I'm upside down
>
> I think I love you
> Taste of whiskey sours
> Always I drink you
>
> If we're under covers
> Let me be the thing that you drink to

I don't know the meaning of: *be under covers*, *tough cry*, and *whiskey sours*.

Comment: Hi Hadimsv. Welcome to the site. Just know, identifying lyrics is off-topic, but explaining their meaning is all good.

Comment: thanks @Aaron- but I didn't get the lyric well , where can I go for identifying the lyrics of songs , is there any specific website you recommend?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for that, but I suggest trying the chat room. Someone here might know the lyrics or be able to point you to a good website.

Answer (score 2):

> *I will cry like the tough cry*

I will cry like a person who is tough (strong) cries.

> If we're under covers

If we're lying in bed together

> whiskey sours

A whiskey sour is a cocktail made with

- bourbon,
- lemon juice, and
- simple syrup,

and typically garnished with a slice of orange and/or a maraschino cherry. Here is [a recipe from Bon Appétit](https://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/whiskey-sour).